# How to call same api multiple times in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using Angular 7, I have an api route that I want to call multiple times (almost 20 times) but with different params. I want that api call to be called again when previous call to that api returns a response. I have a loop that call that api multiple times. Loop is in html using ngFor, which is rendering child component and passing data to child component and child component call that api from ngOnInit(). For example this is the example api

```
'https://demo2081640.mockable.io/events', { params: { ...filters } }
```

Is there any rxjs operator that can do it?

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeUntil

Answer (score 3):

You can prepare the calls in an array and then use the concat operator.

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

const calls$ = [call(1), call(2), call(3)...call(n)]; // you can use an array

concat(calls$).subscribe();
```

The subscribe will be fired for every event emmited from the calls (is sucesses and errors)